# how to use ajax in wordpress to show database columns using php and Json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

I'm new using ajax and I have a code to display from wordpress some information from database columns.
I have this PHP code to connect with the database and create the JSON file:

```
<?php    
$username = $_REQUEST['username']; 
$password = $_REQUEST['password'];    

if (isset($username) && isset($password)) {
//CONEXION
    $host="localhost";
    $user="DB_Username";
    $pass="DB_Password";
    $dbname="DB_Name";

//Conexion
$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$dbname) 
or die("unexpected error");

//gWe made the search
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Column WHERE A_Login='$username'";
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 

if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

$clients = array();

$num_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($num_result == 0) {
        $clients = array("error" => "true", "msg" => "We can't found this user", "data" => $username);
    } else {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
        { 
            $id=$row['ID'];
            $Name=$row['Name'];

            if ($row['A_Login'] == $username && $row['A_Password'] == $password){        
                $clients[] = array('id'=> $id, 'Name'=> $Name);
                } else {
                    $clients[] = array('error'=> "true", "msg" => "Incorrect data");
                    }

        }
    }

$close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
or die("Unespected error with DB");
  }
else {
    $clients = array("error" => "true", "msg" => "You must fill all fields", "username" => $username);
}   
//We build the JSON
$json_string = json_encode($clients);
echo $json_string;

?>
```

In a wordpress page I have this code, I build a form where if the user click the submit button call doLogin()

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function doLogin(){
    data = {username: jQuery("#user").val(), password: jQuery("#pass").val()}
    console.log(data);
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Mywebsiteurl.php",
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(){

    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //var arr = JSON.parse(data);
        //$('#forma').html(data);

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
} </script>
```

I need to show in `<div id="forma">` a kind of list usign html, for example:

Id: VALUE ID
Name: VALUE NAME

and more information...

When i try to print in my website the required information using `$('#forma').html(data);` I obtain error or just an empty space.

How can I fix it? thanks.

Comment: Are the information coming from another database or from the WordPress database ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress we need to hook the ajax hook to your **check_user** function here.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_your_action_from_js', 'your_function');

//Using ajax for non-logged users as well (PUBLIC)
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_your_action_from_js', 'your_function');
```

Check below code for how it is done regarding your context.

In functions.php

```
function check_user() {
    $username = $_REQUEST['username']; 
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];    

    if (isset($username) && isset($password)) {
    //CONEXION
        $host="localhost";
        $user="DB_Username";
        $pass="DB_Password";
        $dbname="DB_Name";

    //Conexion
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass,$dbname) 
    or die("unexpected error");

    //gWe made the search
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Column WHERE A_Login='$username'";
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 

    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();

    $clients = array();

    $num_result = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($num_result == 0) {
            $clients = array("error" => "true", "msg" => "We can't found this user", "data" => $username);
        } else {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            { 
                $id=$row['ID'];
                $Name=$row['Name'];

                if ($row['A_Login'] == $username && $row['A_Password'] == $password){        
                    $clients[] = array('id'=> $id, 'Name'=> $Name);
                    } else {
                        $clients[] = array('error'=> "true", "msg" => "Incorrect data");
                        }

            }
        }

    $close = mysqli_close($conexion) 
    or die("Unespected error with DB");
      }
    else {
        $clients = array("error" => "true", "msg" => "You must fill all fields", "username" => $username);
    }   
    //We build the JSON
    $json_string = json_encode($clients);
    echo $json_string;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_check_user', 'check_user');

//Using ajax for non-logged users as well (PUBLIC)
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_user', 'check_user');
```

In your JS called file.

In the script the **action** is related to your **_your_action_from_js**. So action is needed for knowing where the ajax has to hit. In our case it executes our **check_user** and returns the appropriate values.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function doLogin(){
    data = {action: 'check_user', username: jQuery("#user").val(), password: jQuery("#pass").val()}
    console.log(data);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_url,
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function(){

    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        //var arr = JSON.parse(data);
        //$('#forma').html(data);

    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error");
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
} 
</script>
```

Reference Simple AJAX Form: http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/

CODEX Reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has specific methods to enable ajax requests.

```
// registering ajax request for Logged users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

// registering ajax request also for public area
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );

function my_action_callback() 
{
    // Your code here

    wp_die(); // this is required to terminate immediately and return a proper response
}
```

To call it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {action: "my_action", username: jQuery("#user").val(), password: jQuery("#pass").val()}

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: data,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(a,b,c) {

        }
    });
});
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins